# Beta badge - Will it be awarded now that we are live?

Tags: discussion, badges

I know that some of us already got the beta badge from early stages. Will the badge again be awarded for the rest who have participated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the Beta badge is for people who participated in the *private* Beta, not the public Beta. So, if you were not in the private Beta you're not going to get it, and neither will I.

Comment: Aha.. you might be correct :) I think the badge should say so then to avoid any more confusion.

Comment: Err it does ["Actively participated in the private beta"](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta)